# How to convert expression to a single fraction in Maple?

Tags: integration, fractions, maple

I am trying to use Maple to evaluate some integrals, in the following form:

$$\int\frac{1}{(Z^2 + \alpha^2)^{5/2}}dZ = \frac{Z(3\alpha^2 + 2Z^2)}{3\alpha^4(Z^2 + \alpha^2)^{3/2}}$$

The indefinite integral given there blows up as $\alpha \to 0$; however, the definite integral, given below, is bounded as $\alpha \to 0$:

$$\int_{Z_1}^{Z_2}\frac{1}{(Z^2 + \alpha^2)^{5/2}}dZ = \frac{Z_1(3\alpha^2 + 2Z_1^2)}{3\alpha^4(Z_1^2 + \alpha^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{Z_2(3\alpha^2 + 2Z_2^2)}{3\alpha^4(Z_2^2 + \alpha^2)^{3/2}}$$

However, evaluating the definite integral above using a computer is not going to work, since the two individual terms blow up at $\alpha = 0$ (although the difference doesn't). I am hoping to use Maple to evaluate these integrals, and I am wondering if it is possible to tell Maple to combine the two terms into a single fraction, before evaluating? How can I do that?

(btw. $Z, \alpha$ here are real numbers)

Comment: *(although the difference doesn't)* Are you sure ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, I am pretty sure. I haven't proven the general case, but I have tried several specific values of $Z_1$, $Z_2$ and the $\alpha^4$ in the denominator disappears when you combine the fractions. I think I have found the answer to my question - it seems that using the 'simplify' command in Maple will combine it into a single fraction.